# Opening Visual Studio 2005 C# project with CrystalDecisions

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

First I'm sorry for my bad english it's not my native language.
I'm new to my entreprise and I have to re-code a C# application. This application is in relation with CrystalReport and uses many references called "CrystalDecisions.blabla".

My problem is: by default the project opens with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 but the references to CrystalDecisions are missing. The guy that first developped the app was working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 but the one installed on my computer doesn't support C#, only sql server.

What am i supposed to do? Is there some libs i can download to use on Visual C# 2008? Do I have to reinstall Visual Studio 2005 to have C# supported?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I actually had a file called "CRRedist2005_x86.msi" which I never noticed. After installing those redist the references worked. Thank you guys for your fast answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I wouldn't download a new binaries for `VS 2008`, as considering that previous version was on  `VS 2005`, means that it compiles against `.NET 2.0`, so for supporting original CrystlReport binaries its enough for you to set target framework of your project to version `2.0`
2. It's (I think) almost impossible that you install VS 2008 and don't have a support for C#. I *suppose* you're talking about *ExpressEditions* which are free of charge. Can have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/express/future/bb421473) for downloading C# for 2008. If you wan that. I would suggest, at this point download immidiately the [Visual C# 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I installed the last version of Visual C# and the redist (edited my question) and it's now working. Unfortunatly i can't vote you up but thanks a lot. :)

Comment: "Vote up requires 15 reputation" - I'm totally new to this site i can only check the accepted answer :)

Comment: @Blowi: ah, ok. Didn't even remember that :) By accepting or answering others and be voted, you can increase your vote...

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Reports references are linking to files Visual Studio can't find. Copy tese DLL files to your computer en relink the references.

Comment: I actually installed the Crystal Reports redist which is almost the same. Thanks